# How to get specific value from specific position by substr-instr

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, substr

I have some filename like `'abc-type-bank-20200112-1578796204118.csv'`
i want to get the value `'bank'` from above which is **3rd value** if I cut the string by `'-'`.
If my filename is like `abc-type-XYZ-20200112-1578796204118.csv`, I should get `'XYZ'` from 3rd position.

I was trying to get by below code, but it giving wrong value.

```
select substr(v_FILE_NAME,1,instr(v_FILE_NAME, '-') + 3) as name from (
select 'abc-type-bank-20200112-1578796204118.csv' as v_FILE_NAME from dual);
```

Comment: i tagged oracle and sql for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use SUBSTR and INSTR to extract your desired substring you'd do something like

```
WITH cteData AS (SELECT 'abc-type-bank-20200112-1578796204118.csv' AS FILENAME FROM DUAL),
     ctePos  AS (SELECT FILENAME,
                        INSTR(FILENAME, '-', 1, 2) AS DASH_2_POS,
                        INSTR(FILENAME, '-', 1, 3) AS DASH_3_POS
                   FROM cteData)
SELECT SUBSTR(FILENAME, DASH_2_POS + 1, DASH_3_POS - DASH_2_POS - 1) AS SUBSTR_3
  FROM ctePos
```

The above will extract the substring `'bank'` from the sample data.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=426f73c3ba5d64ebb55e4e53812060f4)

Comment: Thanks, i think its working..... i just needed one liner for all.. so i made this... is that okay ???                 select SUBSTR(v_FILE_NAME,INSTR(v_FILE_NAME, '-', 1, 2)+1, INSTR(v_FILE_NAME, '-', 1, 3) - INSTR(v_FILE_NAME, '-', 1, 2) - 1)   as name from (
select 'abc-type-bank-20200112-1578796204118.csv' as v_FILE_NAME from dual);

Answer (score 1):

The use of dual suggests Oracle.  In that database you can use [`regexp_substr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm):

```
select regexp_substr(filename, '[^-]+', 1, 3)
from (select 'abc-type-XYZ-20200112-1578796204118.csv' as filename from dual) x;
```

Comment: thanks for this... but i cannot use regexp in my case, i have to use this in informatica expression, there i can use substr/instr only. if you can help with :)